# Filtering aggregated values in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `store` and one named `products`.

The data is structured like this:

```
Store table 
ID NAME
1, 'red fruit store';
2, 'blue fruit store';
3, 'orange fruit store';

Fruits table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'orange';
2, 1, 'apple';
3, 1, 'banana';
4, 2, 'apple';
5, 3, 'banana';
6, 3, 'pear';

Vegetables table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'tomato';
2, 1, 'carrot';
3, 1, 'potato';
4, 2, 'cabbage';
5, 3, 'tomato';
6, 3, 'carrot';
```

If I want to select the store having

- oranges
- one or multiple from (banana, apple pear)
- and tomato or carrot

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution using a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT s.ID, MAX(s.NAME) 
FROM Store s INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM Fruits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Vegetables
) t1 ON s.ID = t1.STORE_ID
GROUP BY s.ID
HAVING SUM(t1.PRODUCT_NAME = 'orange') > 0
  AND SUM(t1.PRODUCT_NAME IN ('apple', 'banana', 'pear')) > 0
  AND SUM(t1.PRODUCT_NAME IN ('tomato', 'carrot')) > 0;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4870a708065a1fec3a99e80828d3a23)

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to satisfy the specification. Conditional aggregation approach is given in another answer. We could also use correlated subqueries

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.name
  FROM store s
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM fruits f1
                 WHERE f1.store_id = s.id 
                   AND f1.product_name IN ('orange')
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM fruits f2
                 WHERE f2.store_id = s.id
                   AND f2.product_name IN ('banana','apple','pear')
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM vegetables v3
                 WHERE v3.store_id = s.id 
                   AND v3.product_name IN ('tomato','carrot')
              )
```

Comment: Can you please explain this query. Why SELECT 1, and why f1.store_id - s.id ?

Comment: the subquery in the EXISTS is checking for the existence of a row; it doesn't matter what column(s) or expression(s) we return. There's nothing special about the literal 1 in the SELECT list. We could `SELECT 'foo'` or `SELECT f1.product_name`.  Choosing the literal 1 is just a reminder to the future reader that we are just checking for the existence of a row.

Comment: That condition should be an equality comparison, `f1.store_id = s.id`.  The dash subtraction operator is a typo. I will correct that.